# how to update userprofile in android parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

/* i have created user class which saves username and password in parse.com android,next i used edit button to add profile details and save it along with userid. Now the problem is how to UPDATE the same user profile details ? everytime my new user profile is created. HELP ME GUYZ..!!thank you

```
    profileSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            countryname=country.getText().toString();
            parentname=parent.getText().toString();
            childname=child.getText().toString();
            relationname=relation.getText().toString();

            if(countryname.isEmpty() || parentname.isEmpty() ||childname.isEmpty() ||relationname.isEmpty()){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(MyProfile.this);
                builder.setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage("please fill all the fields")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,null);
                AlertDialog dialog =builder.create();
                dialog.show();

            }else{
                pDialog =new ProgressDialog(MyProfile.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Saving..!!");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                pDialog.show();

                //get current user
                ParseUser parseUser =ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                String userid =parseUser.getObjectId();

                //save data in profile class
                ParseObject mProfile =new ParseObject("Profile");

                mProfile.put("country",countryname);
                mProfile.put("parent",parentname);
                mProfile.put("child",childname);
                mProfile.put("relation",relationname);
                mProfile.put("userid", userid);
                mProfile.saveInBackground();


                Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
                pDialog.dismiss();

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To Update a user profile first you need to check if the profile exists in "Profile" class or not , if exists then you need to update the values of that row , if its not present means you need to create a new  profile object and save it.

Code :

```
 // current user query

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query= ParseUser.getQuery();
    userId= ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    query.whereEqualTo("objectId", userId);

// Profile user query
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> fetchchQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Profile");
    fetchQuery.whereMatchesQuery("userid",query);
    fetchQuery.findObjectsInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException exception)  {

                if(exception == null){
                ParseObject mProfile =new ParseObject("Profile");

                 if(objects.size() > 0){
                 mProfile = objects.get(0);
                }
                mProfile.put("country",countryname);
                mProfile.put("parent",parentname);
                mProfile.put("child",childname);
                mProfile.put("relation",relationname);
                mProfile.put("userid", userid);
                mProfile.saveInBackground();

                }else{
                // error while fetching 
               }


            }
        });
```